# How to get jquery datatables rowindex for a known row number?

Tags: jquery, datatables

For example I need to know the datables row index for row number 2.

I'm not selecting or clicking the row, I just know that it's row number 2 that I want to grab the data for.

Comment: Hello! Please provide a little more data. Like, what exactly do you want to do? Is the data you want to retrieve from row 2 an attribute? Is not very clear in your question.

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use [`row()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29) to get a single row from the table and [`row().data()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29.data%28%29) to get data for that row.

You can pass jQuery selector `tr:eq(1)` to [`row()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29) API method to select second row (zero-based index in `:eq()` CSS selector) and use optional row [`selector-modifier`](http://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier) if needed.

For example, to get data for the second row on the current page with search applied:

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

console.log(table.row('tr:eq(1)', { page: 'current', search: 'applied' }).data());
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1sk0pa4k/2/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable()
```

Then you can grab the 2th visible row using `:eq(1)` - remember the elements array is zerobased - and then pass that to `table.row().rowIndex()` :

```
var row = $('#example tbody tr:eq(1)'),
    rowIndex = table.row(row).index();

alert('row index for visible #2 row is '+rowIndex);
```

`rowIndex()` is the original row order, the way they are ordered in the markup.

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/bL86guq5/**